# Inequality: Norm of difference in exponential of matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, reference-request, normed-spaces, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices. Then,
$$
\|e^{A+B}- e^A\| \leq \|B\|e^{\|A\|+\|B\|}.
$$

Can anyone give me a proof or reference for this inequality, please? Thank you.

Comment: Probably a reposting of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262042

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is mostly just combinatorial and algebraic identities.

Letting $f(0)=A$ and $f(1)=B$, we can distribute terms to get $$(A+B)^n-A^n = \sum_{\sigma\in\{0,1\}^n \\ \;\;\sigma \not\equiv 0} \prod_{j=1}^n f(\sigma(j))$$ Thus \begin{align*}\|(A+B)^n-A^n\| &\leq \sum_{\sigma\in\{0,1\}^n \\ \;\;\sigma \not\equiv 0} \prod_{j=1}^n \|f(\sigma(j))\| \\&= \sum_{k=1}^n {{n}\choose {k}} \|A\|^k \|B\|^{n-k} \\ &= (\|A\|+\|B\|)^n - \|A\|^n \\ &= \|B\| \bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\|A\|+\|B\|)^{n-j-1}\|A\|^{j}\bigg) \\ &\leq n\cdot \|B\| \cdot (\|A\|+\|B\|)^{n-1}\end{align*} In the second line we just used basic combinatorics, in the third line we used the binomial theorem, in the fourth line we used the identity $x^n-y^n = (x-y)\big(\sum_{0}^{n-1} x^jy^{n-1-j}\big)$, and in the last line we just used the fact that $\|A\|^j \leq (\|A\|+\|B\|)^j$ for all $j$.

Therefore 
\begin{align*}
\|e^{A+B}-e^{A}\| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\| (A+B)^n -A^n\|}{n!} \\ &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot \|B\| \cdot (\|A\|+\|B\|)^{n-1}}{n!} \\ &= \|B\|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\| A\|+\|B\|)^n}{n!} \\ &= \|B\|e^{\|A\|+\|B\|}
\end{align*}
This proves the claim. One could also use more advanced methods like Frechet calculus to prove even stronger bounds than this, like $\|e^{B}-e^{A}\| \leq \|B-A\|e^{\max \{\|A\|,\|B\|\}},$ or even better if $A,B$ are symmetric then $\|e^{B}-e^{A}\| \leq \|B-A\|e^{\max \Sigma(A) \cup \Sigma(B)}$.

Comment: Where can I read about these inequalities?

Comment: For the two bounds in the end, what are the references we can look for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof of both bounds can be derived by computing the frechet derivative of the matrix exponential, see e.g. Lemma 3.24 in this paper for a proof of the second bound: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05297.pdf#page28

Comment: And here is a link where they compute that frechet derivative @R.W : https://wj32.org/wp/2013/02/28/frechet-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential-function/

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the references! Indeed these are extremely interesting and relevant inequalities, and you have helped a lot, thank you. Att. RW